# Facebook Integration Into Webpage

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to integrate Facebook into my webpage so users can update their status from my site. Right now I have a button a user clicks to update their status, the button calls the updateFacebookStatus() function. When this button is clicked right now, a blank white window pops up saying "waiting for www.facebook.com". This window is where it should be asking for permission but the window just times out. Any ideas: Here is my code for the function updateFacebookStatus().

```
    function updateFacebookStatus()
    {

//Ask for permissions
    FB.login(function(response) 
    {

    }, {scope:'publish_stream, offline_access,manage_pages'});

     FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) 
     {

//If user is logged it and given permissions update status
      if (response.status === 'connected') 
      {

        new_status = document.getElementById('FacebookBody').value;

        //update status
        FB.api(
        {
            method: 'status.set',
            status: new_status
        },
        function(response)
        {
            if(response == 0)
            {
                alert("Your Facebook Status Was Not Updated.");
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Your Facebook Status Was Updated");
            }
        }

      );} 
      else 
      {
        window.location.href = "#home";
      }
     });
    }
```

In my html file I get the Facebook javascript sdk using the following code:

```
        <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
        <script>
              FB.init({
                appId  : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                status : true, // check login status
                cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                xfbml  : true, // parse XFBML
                channelUrl : 'http://www.XXXXX.com/channel.html', // channel.html file
                oauth  : true // enable OAuth 2.0
              });

              // Load the SDK Asynchronously
              (function(d){
                 var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
                 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
                 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
                 ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
               }(document));
        </script>
```

Comment: The code seems to get stuck on the 
"FB.login(function(response)" line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure if it has anything to do with your problem but notice that you call the same script twice - one time via `<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>` tag and the other via async function call under `// Load the SDK Asynchronously`

Comment: Ya I know, it's weird but the window only pops up when I have both.